# Vertically center content with different heights using flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a layout using `flex-direction: column` with divs that have different specified heights. If you specify different heights for divs that share the same flexbox parent I find that the vertical alignment disappears.

I have tried all sorts of combinations using `align-items`, `align-content`, `justify-content` to no avail. I have used `flex-grow` in place of the height rule which also has no effect. The only way I can get the content to vertically center is if I make the items all the same relative height.

[Here is my issue.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rymoor)

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40em;
  background-color: #badabf;
}

.site-title {
  height: 32em;
  background-color: #DEA5A4;
}

.site-navigation {
  height: 8em;
  background-color: #AEC6CF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="site-title">
    <h1> I am a page title </h1>
    <img src="http://www.nintendo.com/images/social/fb-400x400.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <nav class="site-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Until I can get a good understanding of how to use flexbox effectively I will probably go back to creating layouts without flexbox. I really want to start using it soon, it feels much less hacky despite this issue I am having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a flex formatting context is the parent-child relationship.

In other words, flex layout exists only between the flex container and its children.

Descendants beyond the children do not participate in flex layout.

The elements you're targeting are children of a flex item (`.site-title`), so flex properties don't apply.

You will have to make flex items into flex containers to make flex properties work deeper in the HTML structure.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40em;
  background-color: #badabf;
}

.site-title {
  height: 32em;
  background-color: #DEA5A4;
  display: flex;                 /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column;        /* NEW */
  align-items: center;           /* NEW */
  justify-content: center;       /* NEW */
}

.site-navigation {
  height: 8em;
  background-color: #AEC6CF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="site-title">
    <h1> I am a page title </h1>
    <img src="http://www.nintendo.com/images/social/fb-400x400.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <nav class="site-navigation">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, I came to this conclusion after much head banging as well. It is always the simple answers or problems that give me the most trouble.